# What does "commit of the task output" mean in OutputCommitter

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I was reading documentation about the OutputCommitter of MapReduce framework and I don't understand this particular explanation:
"Commit of the task output. Once task is done, the task will commit it’s output if required."

Comment: Is it about moving the output data to HDFS or something like that?

Comment: You incorporate your comment into the question by editing the question and then delete the comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally it just means moving the output from a temp directory to the specified output directory. Usually, both of these directories are on HDFS.

Answer (score 0):

> The commit phase for tasks is optional, and may be disabled by returning false from needsTaskCommit(). This saves the framework from having to run the distributed commit protocol for the task, and neither commitTask() nor abortTask()is called. FileOutputCommitter will skip the commit phase when no output has been written by a task.
>   If a task succeeds then  commitTask()is called, which in the default implementation moves the temporary task output directory (which has the task attempt ID in its name to  avoid  conflicts  between  task  attempts)  to  the  final  output  path,  ${mapred.output.dir}.

**Note: this paragraph from hadoop-The definitive guide and may be useful for this question